# Rails double encoding my json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am trying to return an object which contains an array of other objects and i am getting back the objects all escaped eg(`\"name\":\"My Name\"`).  I'm sure the problem is i am double encoding but I'm a ruby n00b so I am not sure how to do this properly

```
@Results = Marker.where("ID = '#{params[:id]}' and Stop_Id IS null").all

format.all { render json: { :Results => @Results.to_json(:include => :stops) } }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you already did a render as json and why do you convert the results to json again.

Comment: as @Rocky says, you should simply do `render json: { :Results => @Results }`

Comment: @apneadiving when I just do `render json: { :Results => @Results }` it doesn't include the associated stops... I need that data, sorry I am not sure how to include them otherwise.

Comment: see http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Comment: Thank you so much, I am getting my Json back how I want it.
I have one more problem seemingly associated with this.

undefined method `Name' for #<Marker:0x35f3148>

in my class I have
attr_accessible :Lat, :Name, :Lng

super({Lat: self.Lat, Lng: self.Lng, Name: self.Name, include: [:stops]})

It won't allow me to use Name for some reason?

Comment: @apneadiving (Solved that second question I had on my own) Do you want to answer it so I can mark it as correct and closed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `as_json` method in your model.

[See here for advice.](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)